# function for scrabble type game not working (MIT 6.0001 pset 3:)

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop

The following code doesn't execute and I don't know why. I get 'syntax error when I try to run it.

```
SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2,
'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1,
'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1,
'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
}


def get_word_score(word, n):
    char_values = 0
    for char in word:
        char_values += SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[char.lower()]
    if 1 >= (7*len(word) - 3*(n-len(word))):
        print (char_values * 1)
    else:
        print (char_values * (7*len(word) - 3*(n-len(word)))



get_word_score('lazxocijhoaewsfj', 5)
```

Comment: Where it fails?

Comment: I forgot to add a parentheses at the end. If I add the parentheses the function works.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenthesis for the `print` statement in the `else`:

```
def get_word_score(word, n):
    char_values = 0
    for char in word:
        char_values += SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[char.lower()]
    if 1 >= (7*len(word) - 3*(n-len(word))):
        print (char_values * 1)
    else:
        print (char_values * (7*len(word) - 3*(n-len(word)))) # <-- Need another )
```